# Search records by date range & if date range is empty using SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have created search web form using C#, asp.net. I have search parameters like customer name, date range(from & to). I have written query for searching by above parameter. Its working fine, but when I am searching only by customer name not by date range then it does not show records. Please give me solution to give condition for empty date range same as **'%'** operator in **'LIKE'** condition.

Comment: post your sql query. are u using dynamic sql ?

Comment: select custname, fromdate,todate from custleavetable where  custname like '%" + txtcustname.text + "%' and fromdate between  '" + txtfrom.text + "' AND '" + txtto.text + "' and todate between  '" + txtfrom.text + "' AND '" + txtto.text + "'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you are passing following 3 parameter to the SP

```
@Input VARCHAR(100)
@FromDate DATETIME
@ToDate DATETIME
```

When you want to search only on the basis of customer name in this case pass ***NULL*** value for the ***FromDate*** and ***ToDate*** and write your query like following.

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3....  
FROM TABLET1 T1
WHERE T1.Name LIKE '%' + @Input  + '%'
AND (T1.FROMDATE >= @FromDate OR @FromDate IS NULL)
AND (T1.TODATE <= @ToDate OR @ToDate IS NULL)
```

**Case 1** : FromDate not specified in the UI so **@FromDate** will be **NULL** and condition AND `(T1.FROMDATE >= @FromDate OR **@FromDate IS NULL**)` will return true.

**Case 2** : ToDate not specified in the UI so **@ToDate** will be **NULL** and condition ND `(T1.TODATE <= @ToDate OR @ToDate IS NULL)` will return true.

**Case 3:** Both From date and To date not specified in that case both the above conditions (Case 1 and Case 2) will be true and query will return all the matching records on the basis of `T1.Name LIKE '%' + @Input  + '%'`

Comment: if i have not entered date range for search & only if i search by name then it does not show any record (records having from date & to date), this query does not work

Comment: I think you have not checked the where clause properly. It will definitely return the matching records. I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: This works fine without SP, i have to give conditions in SP, but am fetching data from multiple tables, so how can i put them in one stored procedure(This SP belongs to one table only)

Comment: You can use SQL JOIN statements to combine data from multiple tables. I think you should read about the SQL JOIN and queries in more detail. Above query is just a sample query using a single table which cab be extended easily using joins as per your requirement.

Comment: i used join only to fetch data from multiple tables, but i have to do with SP, is it possible?

Comment: You can wrap any query into a SP. What is the problem?